# What is maximum number of equality constraints in Scipy's SLSQP algorithm?

Tags: optimization, scipy

I am using following code to optimize a set of parameters using Scipy's optimize module:

```
slsqp_res = minimize(obj_func, params, method='SLSQP', constraints= eq_cons)
```

where obj_func is my objective function, params is a vector of initial parameter values and eq_cons is a set of equality constraints. I tried different equality constraints but some times I get this error:

```
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 618, in minimize
  constraints, callback=callback, **options)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 329, in _minimize_slsqp
  w = zeros(len_w)
ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

I guess this is because in some cases my equality constraints are excessive. My question is what is the maximum possible number of equality constraints in the SLSQP algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

This message seems to come from the workspace calculation:

```
# Define the workspaces for SLSQP
n1 = n + 1
mineq = m - meq + n1 + n1
len_w = (3*n1+m)*(n1+1)+(n1-meq+1)*(mineq+2) + 2*mineq+(n1+mineq)*(n1-meq) \
        + 2*meq + n1 + ((n+1)*n)//2 + 2*m + 3*n + 3*n1 + 1
len_jw = mineq
w = zeros(len_w)   <-----
jw = zeros(len_jw)
```

Python integers should not overflow (they are bigints), but inside numpy functions we can easily overflow.

Note that SLSQP is a dense code meant for small/medium-sized problems. For large problems, you may want to look at a sparse solver like IPOPT.